# What do you call someone who you show a game to and then they binge plays the game until they are better than you?

Tags: meaning, grammar, terminology

My so called "*friend* " likes to play video games **a lot**. We like to play Roblox (*We aren't 5 yr olds*). So one day I found this awesome game called **RoBeats** and I loved to play it. One day I got so good I was able to get **A+s** On level 7 levels. One day I showed him the game and we played for a while. I eventually got bored and went to bed. When I woke up he was **STILL** playing the game. This kept going on for days and seeing him online playing the game. One day I decided to play with him and he was **WAY** better than me. Do you have a name for a person like this?  It would be used like:

> *You're still playing?  You're such a ______.*

Comment: Did he do it just to annoy you, or make you feel stupid?

Comment: Welcome, Rainbow! It would help if you could attribute the feeling associated with that characteristic because it could be anything, really.  Please read how to ask a question for a -word requests.

Comment: Of course he was better than you if he was constantly playing for ages... Do you mean he was going out of his way to improve just so he could beat *you*? (This isn't a social comment, just wondering if this is the word you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

**bangout** or **try-hard**

> someone who plays [games] nonstop or takes a game too seriously.

This is partly my own definition because these words hardly appear on the Internet, but I believe it is accurate.

These are informal slang words, and since 'bangout' is London slang, the only mention I can find of it is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/64jrod/what_does_bangout_mean/).

> *You're **still** playing FIFA? You're such a **bangout***.

**tryhard** or **try-hard** is mostly self-explanatory, but the meaning is here:
They quote:

> *Basically, If any activity is just for fun, and you’re taking it too seriously… you’re a try hard.*

https://yr.media/tech/definition-of-a-try-hard/

Comment: If you're going to cite a source, please include their definition in your answer instead of just a link since links can be broken or lost.  I can't tell if your definition is from a source or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Binge Gamer" for these occasions.
But this word is *not* reliable because you can't find it on dictionaries.
And also the verb form is "Binge Gaming".

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the part the OP stresses that the other person to whom you showed the game ultimately is better than you at it.  To me, it isn't clear what the OP is trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

That person would be **too competitive**.

Joey is **too competitive**.  If he's playing against a 7 year-old he won't even let the poor kid score.